# Terminal in IntelliJ is not working properly - but normal zsh terminal is working fine

Tags: java, intellij-idea, terminal, zsh

I am unable to perform even basic commands in the IntelliJ terminal.[image: screenshot of intellij terminal after launching]

I've tried the command `source ~/.zshrc` but that doesn't help.

Answer (score 3):

You can try to press `ctrl+alt+S` and choose the terminal menu settings. There you can see the option `Shell Path`, for me it:

[image: tools -> Terminal]

You should set the path to distribution zsh.exe

After that close your terminal and start it again.

Answer (score 1):

I found [this](https://nhancv.medium.com/fix-terminal-bin-zsh-does-not-work-in-intellij-idea-v2018-3-1-macos-1e025c03823f)

It said to change /Applications/IntelliJ\ IDEA.app/Contents/plugins/terminal/.zshrc from its original content to:

```
function override_jb_variables {
  for VARIABLE in $(env)
  do
    NAME=${VARIABLE%%=*}
    if [[ $NAME = '_INTELLIJ_FORCE_SET_'* ]]
    then
      NEW_NAME=${NAME:20}
      if [ -n "$NEW_NAME" ] && [ "$NEW_NAME" != "PATH" ]
      then
        VALUE=${VARIABLE#*=}
        export "$NEW_NAME"="$VALUE"
      fi
    fi
  done
}
override_jb_variables
```